# c4710 Function is not included std::basic_ostream

Tags: c++, c++11

I am getting error:

```
C4710   class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &
__ptr64 __cdecl std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __ptr64 (__cdecl*)(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __ptr64))
__ptr64: function is not included
```

on line:

```
std::cerr << "clBuildProgram failed" << std::endl;
```

I don't understand what doesn't mean.

It's basic writing to error stream, what function do I need to write to the error stream?

Comment: Did you remember to include `iostream`? A simple int main with that line works for me. Maybe `;` missing on previous line?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seems to be an error but a warning you can ignore: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4710

It's a kind of optimisation you can probably ignore.

Remind that **errors** lead to compilation failure and need a strong repair. **Warning** do not lead to failure but need your attention. Some of them could be safely ignored (as this one) but most need to rethink about the way you are coding.